# IIS website inaccessible from server (but ok from outside)

Tags: asp.net, iis, web

On a server where an IIS website is hosted, if I open IE or Firefox and type the IIS website url,  i got an error after a few seconds ("Cannot display the webpage", just like website would be offline). If I do the same from the exterior (as normal user do) everything works.

I have tried to give the IP address directly (thus skipping DNS), problem is the same. It only works if I type the internal ip address of the IIS website (eg : 10.0.0.x).

The reason I want to do that is that I need to access a specific page of the website in order to execute a scheduled task. I cannot use internal ip address to do that, because host name (`HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host`)  is used inside ASP.NET code to switch between different configuration.

Here is my question : **is it possible to access a specific page on a IIS website from server where website is hosted ? (using complete url, not internal ip address ?)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - If I understand your question correctly you should be able to add a mapping in your local hosts file to point that domain at your IIS webserver.

e.g.

10.0.0.x my.example.hostname

(where x is obviously a number)

We use this configuation internally when developing multiple sites on our local machines - each site is bound to a specific hostname and all these hostnames have mappings in the 'hosts' file to 127.0.0.1

The same principal applies here, if I've understood the question correctly :)

Comment: I tried what you suggested and... yes, it works (thanks!). Anyway i dont understand why it is needed. When i type the url it should do the following (just like any other website...) : url -> dns -> public ip  (->) (die here) private ip -> asp.net.